# Big size static array required

Tags: c++, visual-c++, multidimensional-array, stack

I want a big sized array in a program.

My code has a structure which contains 3 float type variables and I want a largely sized 3 dimensional arrays of this structure.
My code is giving the output for small sized arrays, but when I increase the size of the array, I get a stack overflow exception/error.

Please help.

Comment: Short answer: Create it on the heap.

Comment: How large is your array? If it doesn't fit on the stack, allocate it on the heap.

Comment: Your stack is not very big, maybe on the order of 8-16 MB or so.  Your compiler might have some options for increasing the stack size, but you really should just allocate the array either statically at global scope, or dynamically on the heap.

Comment: float d[15][15][15][15][15];
this is 5 dimensional array i need it.
what is heap ?

Comment: If you really need all of those dimensions, I'd wrap it into a 1D vector.

Comment: 'Create it on the heap' means you've to use the 'new' keyword to allocate the memory for the array.

Comment: Whoa, you *need* a 5-dimensional array?

Comment: add the new operater to allocate to the heap. Just remember to delete it later

Comment: @KaranArora [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap) is a good explanation for you.

Comment: @EitanT, I knew that was residing somewhere, thanks.

Comment: allocating with global scope worked thanks!

Comment: You're gonna need a bigger boat.

Comment: at first: i'm wondering what is the reason for using floats to layout a multidimensional array, as indices sure are of uint type. can you give an example what the values of those floats may be? do you need a 1.21212 x 6.23454 x 195.2322 array? shall the dimensions exceed MAX_INT?

Comment: @captain obvlious: perhaps he is in need of even a bigger float ;)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
int main() {
   float array[N][N][N][N][N];
   ...
```

write

```
float array[N][N][N][N][N];

int main() {
   ...
```

Alternatively, write:

```
int main() {
   static float array[N][N][N][N][N];
   ...
```

BTW: my default setup in VC10/Win32 allows stack allocation up to `N=12`, which means ~ 990KB.

regards

rbo

Comment: yes this is working.
you can also increase the value of N by changing the memory reserved for stack. Its 1Mb by default.

Answer (score 2):

The made-for solution here is [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). It allocates memory on the heap, which is much larger than the stack, and can change its size without much extra effort at all.

```
typedef std::vector<float> vec;
typedef std::vector<vec> vec2D;
typedef std::vector<vec2D> vec3D;
typedef std::vector<vec3D> vec4D;
typedef std::vector<vec4D> vec5D;

vec5D d (15, vec4D (15, vec3D (15, vec2D (15, vec (15)))));
//use as you would a normal array for the most part
```

Of course having a 5D array (as mentioned "needed" in the comments) isn't something you particularly want. I recommend you make a `Matrix` class of sorts that has an underlying 1D vector instead.

Even better, rethink your design. There's rarely a time when you actually do need a highly multidimensional array such as that one.

Comment: The part about std::array is not true - the memory is not allocated dynamically.

Comment: @jrok, I could've sworn I've seen/had this discussion, and it was on the heap. I'll have to find it.

Comment: Thanks for the information on the allocating memory on heap.
Actually  have 1 array of volume elements which is 3D , and a surface element which is 2D , and I need a distance between the 2.

Comment: @jrok, Ah, yes, that wasn't `std::array`. Let me fix that then.

Comment: And i think 5D array is best suited for it, bcoz i can recall a particular distance easily, 
BTW now the code is working, i do it by changing the stack size and global allocation

Answer (score 1):

In addition to allocating it on the heap, you could simply try to reserve a bigger stack, using [/F](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [/STACK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8cxs58a6) option, or in project properties:

[image]

Comment: Come on guys, you don't give a knife to a baby here.  Have him choose a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you need to, but if you want, you may change the default stack size with linker options, for example in Visual Studio go "Properties - Configuration Properties - Linker - System - Stack Reserve Size".

Comment: No - this is not the solution.  Either malloc it or make it a global.  Better yet, use a better data structure :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Windows differentiate between reserving and committing the memory, so reserving enough stack space in advance may not be as wasteful as may seem at the first glance.

Comment: He wanted stack - he gets stack :)